# How to find a tangent line with 2 points of tangency for a curve?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

Say I have a function like this:

```
f[x_] := 4 x^4 - 9 x^3 - x^2 + 10;
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

It's obvious that there's a tangent line with 2 points of tangency here:

[image]

The problem is, how can I find this line programmatically for any such curve given?

---

UPDATE: Sorry, I lied. My function is actually `f[\[CurlyPhi]_] := 1.100955 \[CurlyPhi] (1 - \[CurlyPhi]) + \[CurlyPhi]/9.99968*
  Log[\[CurlyPhi]] + (1 - \[CurlyPhi]) Log[1 - \[CurlyPhi]]`, which, even with a "Rationalize" at the head, yields a error message as follows:

> This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Introduction:

We are looking for two distinct values of $x$ for which a generic line and your function have 1) the same $y$ value (i.e. the line touches the curve) and 2) the same derivative (i.e. the line is tangent to the curve).

We can set up the following system of equations spelling out these conditions:

```
y[x_] := a x + b                      (* a generic line *)
f[x_] := 4 x^4 - 9 x^3 - x^2 + 10;    (* your function  *)

sol = List@ToRules@Reduce[
    {y[x1] == f[x1],
     y'[x1] == f'[x1],
     y[x2] == f[x2],
     y'[x2] == f'[x2],
     x2 != x1},
    {x1, x2}
  ]
```

[image: solutions]

Notice that `Solve` wouldn't work here, because there are no *general solutions* valid for all values of the parameters (indeed, Solve will return the empty set). `Reduce` will generate conditions valid for *some* values of the parameters $a$ and $b$, which is what we are looking for. `Reduce` returns equations as results, but I converted those to substitution rules for plotting.

```
Plot[
  {f[x], y[x] /. sol}, {x, -1, 2},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015], Point[{{x1, f[x1]}, {x2, f[x2]}}] //. sol}
]
```

[image: plot]

### A self-contained function:

We can package this in a function:

```
Clear[doubleTangent]
doubleTangent[f_, range_ /; VectorQ[range, NumericQ] && Dimensions[range] == {2}] :=
 Module[
  {x1, x2, a, b, y, sol},
  y[x_] := a x + b;
  sol = Solve[{
       f[x1] == y[x1], f[x2] == y[x2],
       f'[x1] == y'[x1], f'[x2] == y'[x2], x1 != x2},
     {x1, x2, a, b}, Reals
   ];
  Plot[
   {f[x], y[x] /. sol},
   Evaluate@Flatten@{x, range},
   PlotLegends -> {"function", "tangent"},
   Epilog -> {
     ReplaceRepeated[
      {
       PointSize[0.02],
       Tooltip[Point[{#, f[#]}], Round[{#, f[#]}, 0.01]] & /@ {x1, x2}
      },
      N@sol
     ],
     Inset[
      "a = " <> ToString[N[a /. First@sol]] <> "\nb = " <> ToString[N[b /. First@sol]],
      Scaled[{0.9, 0.9}], Alignment -> Left
     ]
   }
  ]
]
```

This function will return the same result found above, with annotations, when used as follows:

```
doubleTangent[4 #^4 - 9 #^3 - #^2 + 10 &, {-1, 2}]
```

[image: old example with doubleTangent]

Yet another case:

```
doubleTangent[3 #^4 - 12 #^2 + 5 # + 9 &, {-3, 3}]
```

[image: another example]

### Using a numerical solver for non-polynomial functions:

Here is a version relying on a **numerical solver** (`FindRoot`) to solve the system of equations in those cases in which Solve or Reduce are unable to provide a solution. Of course, the method is quite a bit more brittle, and initial (even rough) estimates must be provided of the positions of the points of tangency. It is fiddly, but it works nonetheless :-)

```
Clear[doubleTangentNumeric]

doubleTangentNumeric[
  f_,
  range_ /; VectorQ[range, NumericQ] && Dimensions[range] == {2},
  initval_ /; VectorQ[initval, NumericQ] && Dimensions[initval] == {2}
  ] := Module[
  {x1, x2, a, b, y, sol},
  y[x_] := a x + b;
  (* This is the BIG CHANGE; using a numerical solver rather than Solve or Reduce *)
  sol = FindRoot[
     {f[x1] == y[x1],
      f[x2] == y[x2],
      f'[x1] == y'[x1],
      f'[x2] == y'[x2]},
     {{x1, initval[[1]]},
      {x2, initval[[2]]},
      {a, 1}, {b, 1}},
     WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxIterations -> 1000
   ];
  Plot[
   {f[x], y[x] /. sol},
   Evaluate@Flatten@{x, range},
   PlotLegends -> {"function", "tangent"},

   (* Replaced First@sol with sol, since only one solution is returned by FindRoot *)
   Epilog -> {
     ReplaceRepeated[{PointSize[0.02], 
       Tooltip[Point[{#, f[#]}], Round[{#, f[#]}, 0.01]] & /@ {x1, x2}}, N@sol],
     Inset[
      "a = " <> ToString[N[a /. sol]] <> "\nb = " <> ToString[N[b /. sol]],
      Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}], Alignment -> Left]
     }
  ]
]
```

We can now try it on the function [from your comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110668/how-to-find-a-tangent-line-with-2-points-of-tangency-for-a-curve/110674?noredirect=1#comment300374_110674):

```
f = Log[1 - #1] (1 - #1) + (3125 Log[#1] #1)/31249 + (73666 (1 - #1) #1)/66911 &;

doubleTangentNumeric[f, {0, 1}, {0.1, 0.9}]
```

[image: numerical results]

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution on my function `Rationalize[1.100955 \[CurlyPhi] (1 - \[CurlyPhi]) + \[CurlyPhi]/9.99968*
  Log[\[CurlyPhi]] + (1 - \[CurlyPhi]) Log[1 - \[CurlyPhi]], 10^-10]`, but I got "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce". Any idea how can I get over this?

Comment: @tslmy That function will stretch the abilities of `Solve` (which is essentially a polynomial solver), and probably of `Reduce` as well. Let me see if I can modify the answer to use numerical root finding instead.

Comment: @tslmy OK I've added a new version of `doubleTangent` to the bottom of my answer that uses a numerical solver and can deal with the function you mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

The tangent line at $x = a$ is given by $f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$.  So we can define:

```
tangent[a_, x_] := f[a] + f'[a] (x - a)
slope[a_] = Coefficient[tangent[a, x], x]
intercept[a_] = Coefficient[tangent[a, x], x, 0]
```

Then we want to find two distinct points $a$ and $b$ which have the same tangent line:

```
sln = Simplify@Solve[{slope[a] == slope[b], intercept[a] == intercept[b], b > a}, {a, b}]
```

> `{{a -> 1/16 (9 - 5 Sqrt[11]), b -> 1/16 (9 + 5 Sqrt[11])}}`

There is one solution.

```
Plot[{f[x], tangent[a, x] /. sln}, {x, -1, 2}]
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

```
f2 = D[f[x], x]
x1 /. NSolve[{(f2 /. x -> x1) == (f2 /. 
       x -> x2), (f[x2] - f[x1])/(x2 - x1) == (f2 /. x -> x1)}, {x1, 
    x2}][[1]]
x2 /. NSolve[{(f2 /. x -> x1) == (f2 /. 
       x -> x2), (f[x2] - f[x1])/(x2 - x1) == (f2 /. x -> x1)}, {x1, 
    x2}][[1]]
```

which for your definition of f[x] results in
`x1=-0.473945` and `x2=1.59895`
PS:
Note that

```
NSolve[{(f2 /. x -> x1) == (f2 /. 
     x -> x2), (f[x2] - f[x1])/(x2 - x1) == (f2 /. x -> x1)}, {x1, 
  x2}]
```

gives alternative coordinates:

```
{{x1 -> -0.473945, x2 -> 1.59895}, {x1 -> 1.59895, x2 -> -0.473945}}
```

Answer (score 3):

An interesting alternative---and nice in that it is the shortest and almost the most automated so far---but one that I'm not *entirely* sure I understand, for reasons to be given along the way:

```
f[x_] := 4 x^4 - 9 x^3 - x^2 + 10;
expr = Series[f[x], {x, a, 1}] // Normal;
sols = DeleteDuplicates@SolveAlways[expr == (expr /. a -> b), x];
Plot[{f[x], expr /. #}, {x, -1, 2}] & /@ Thread[a -> (a /. sols)]
```

[image]

You can see that a couple of the solutions match the one we're looking for, most of the rest *seem* to match inflection points (not verified), and the last is the trivial solution `a -> b`.

Here is another example, taken from [MarcoB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27951/marcob)'s [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110674/29734):

```
f[x_] = 3 x^4 - 12 x^2 + 5 x + 9;
expr = Series[f[x], {x, a, 1}] // Normal;
sols = DeleteDuplicates@SolveAlways[expr == (expr /. a -> b), x];
Plot[{f[x], expr /. #}, {x, -3, 3}] & /@ Thread[a -> (a /. sols)]
```

[image]

Again, it seems to work in that it finds the solution, but it finds others, too. I will think on this when I have the time.

Comment: How is this type of link which directs you to a specific answer? How do I find it?[http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110674/29734]

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho . I don't really understand your question!

Comment: How you got the link to the answer made by MarcosB? It is to `share`?

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho . Yeah! Clock the share button below the post.