# Tangent point coordinates when the curve is a set of points

Tags: equation-solving, fitting

I want to find the coordinates of the tangent point between a convex curve and a line that passes from a point with known coordinates `(0,b)` ("efficient portfolio" in finance). My problem is that the curve formula ("efficient frontier") is not known, hence it can only be inferred from a set of pre-calculated points. Important points.

1) I am only interested in the upper part of the curve starting from the left-most point.
2) The tangent point is unique.
3) Quadratic `Fit` did not work (please see below) since it failed at the more convex part on the left (the curve may appear flat).

The output should ideally be a set of coordinates (x,y) or a set of rules.

I provide a dataset for the curve in a DropBox link [here...](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xq0xgidyku0m86/dat.txt?dl=0)

...a plot of the quadratic `Fit` curve in **blue** together with the plotted data in **red** ("efficient frontier") and a general drawing of the solution.

```
bill = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x]
Show[ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.1}, {0, 0.05}}, 
PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[bill, {x, 0, 0.1}]]
```

[image]
[image]

I know there are many similar topics, but all the ones I found refer to tangents where the equation is known. I include a toy code that produces a solution based on MarcoB's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110668/how-to-find-a-tangent-line-with-2-points-of-tangency-for-a-curve) for `b=2` but I don't know how meaningful it is since the curve function is known.

```
y[x_] := a x + 2                     
f[x_] := 3 x^2 - 2 x + 5
sol = List@ToRules@Reduce[{y[x1] == f[x1], y'[x1] == f'[x1]}, {x1}]
Plot[{f[x], y[x] /. sol}, {x, -2, 2}, 
Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015], Point[{x1, f[x1]}] //. sol}]
```

> {{a -> -8, x1 -> (2 + a)/6}, {a -> 4, x1 -> (2 + a)/6}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the curve is convex and $(0, b)$ is "outside" the curve, you can use the convex hull of the point and data.

```
b = -0.01;
bp = {0., b};
hull = ConvexHullMesh[Join[{bp}, data]];
c = MeshCoordinates@hull;
p = Position[c, bp][[1, 1]];
l = Cases[MeshCells[hull, 1], (* lines containing bp *)
   Line[i : {___, p, ___}] :> i];
m = First@Ratios@First@Differences@c[[#]] & /@ l;   (* slopes of those lines *)
(* tp = line segment with greatest slope containing the point bp *)
tp = InfiniteLine[ c[[ l~Part~Last@Ordering[m] ]] ]
(*  InfiniteLine[{{0.0270945, 0.0108}, {0., -0.01}}]  *)

Show[
 ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.1}, {0, 0.05}}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Graphics[{Point[bp], tp}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for your help, this does exactly what I wanted. I could never code something like that since I am not familiar with mesh functions. Many thanks again!

Comment: I do not find ["Coordinates"] as an option in MMa v 12.3. I do find "MeshCoordinates" but it does not work. Any chance this changed with an upgrade of MMa?

Comment: @Rogo Thanks for the notice.  I think I fixed it.  I found both properties in V12.3, but neither worked.  There’s `MeshCoordinates[]`, though, so I used that.

Comment: @Michael E2Got it! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[slope, opt]
slope[rf_] := Divide @@ Reverse[rf - #] &;
opt[dt_, rf_] := dt[[First @ Ordering[slope[rf] /@ dt, -1]]];

rfp = {0., -.01};
opt[data, rfp]
```

> {0.0270945, 0.0108}

```
Row[Show[ListLinePlot[data, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{rfp, opt[data, rfp]}] }, 
     ImageSize -> Medium], 
    Plot[rf[[-1]] + x slope [rf][opt[data, rfp]] , {x, 0, 0.2}, 
     PlotStyle -> Green], 
    PlotRange -> #] & /@ {{-0.02, .07}, {{0, .07}, {-0.02, .03}}}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

You could also use the simpler but slower:

```
opt[dt_, rf_] := Last @ SortBy[dt, slope[rf]];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very interesting because it does not use the curve but maximises the slope for a given dataset, which is also valid. I understand how `opt` is built, but could you explain `slope`?

Comment: @Titus, `slope` takes a reference point (`rf ={x0,y0}`) and for any point `{x1,y1}`  to find the ratio of vertical displacement (`y1-y0`) to horizontal displacement (`x1-x0`) it (1) finds the difference `{x0,y0} - {x1,y1}` (which is, `{x0-x1, y0 - y1}`), (2) `Reverse`s the result (to get `{y0-y1, x0-x1}`), then (3) `Divide`s the result to get `(y0 - y1)/(x0-x1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm a little bit late.

Perhaps this approach finds your interest.
I try to calculate the minimal cone(peak at {0,0} ) including all points!

```
a = {a1, a2};(* centre line of cones *)
opt = NMinimize[{ Max[Map[Abs@ArcCos[ a.(#/Sqrt[#.#])]  &, data]] ,a.a == 1 }, a];  
ak = a /. opt[[2]]; (* optimal cone axis*)
dk = opt[[1]]  (* optimal cone angle*)

Show[{ListPlot[data],Graphics[{Opacity[.2], Red, 
Polygon[2 {{0, 0}, RotationMatrix[dk]. ak, RotationMatrix[-dk]. ak, {0, 0}}], Line[1.3 { {0, 0}, ak}] }]}, PlotRange -> {{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, All, {{0, .2}, {0, .1}}}[[-1]],AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

The minimization can easily be extended to higher order dimensions.